# antlr: can I have the generated java file extends an existing class

Tags: java, antlr

The question is simple, can I have the java source code (e.g. FooParser.java) generated from my grammar file Foo.g extends an existing java class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think option superClass=MySuperClass; will work for you.

Comment: thanks! Is there any requirements on this `MySuperClass`? Say it must be sub class of `org.antlr.runtime.Parser`?

Comment: @green, depending on the type of grammar, it usually is one of: `Lexer`, `Parser`, or `TreeParser`.